# Vagrant workflow: Share the box or share the setup code

Tags: vagrant

Using Vagrant to have a number of developers share the same environment I see two approaches that people are using.

1. Create a box file with entire basic environment installed, and share it on Vagrant cloud?
2. Create a setup script that will "apt-get install" and "git clone" everything that is needed?

With 1st approach I don't like the fact that you have to host large files, also changes to environment would be harder to do (uploading the subsequent version of the entire box?).

Answer (score 1):

Its difficult to make an answer for this, I can only share my experience, I started with #1 and provided a full box to my team, the box was 13 GB but it worked fine (although was not too easy to share), then when we had to upgrade any 3rd party software its was more difficult (it was also before the time `vagrant update` was available) but still I like option #2 much more flexible now. The provisioning takes 2-3 hours but we can run it at night, repeat the process anytime and at the end, its much easier to provision a new instance for a new member.

Comment: Thanks, that's really helpful insight. I was thinking on the same lines. Were you using Chef or Puppet, Bash script?

Comment: we use a mix of puppet and bash script. chef vs puppet is really a matter of preferences as both can achieve the same, looks for current modules/recipies for the soft that you have to install